# 90s Science fiction children's book with glass grass

Tags: story-identification

I read this science fiction story in 5th grade that had a female main character and she was on this alternate planet and the grass was like glass. Does that ring any bells for anyone. Would have been mid 90s when I read it.

Comment: As Valorum says, just take a look at that and if it is a dupe let us know and we can link them, otherwise I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can add any more details.

Comment: Thanks for this guys-- I was thinking of The Green Book, which you linked me in the first post. Thanks I've been wondering about this for the last decade!